# Why isn't contenteditable working?

Tags: html, contenteditable

I'm trying to get contenteditable to work on a style element but it doesn't seem to be changing anything and the other styles dont seem to be being applied

```
  <style contenteditable="true" style="display: block; width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black;">

  </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this it's working.

```
<style contenteditable="true" style="display: block; width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black;">

  </style>
<div class="x"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/sefalette-1472316262/pen/KqxwVY